# Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: DBClientBase::findN: transport error

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

i have used this website for years but this is my first time asking a question, so feel free to correct me if i don't do it right.

We are running into this problem a lot lately.
We have mongos running one multiple Centos5 servers connecting to sharded replicaset mongodb servers running 2.4.9.

Recently we did a lot of optimization which increased our throughput and while this problem used to happen a lot before, it's now become intolerable.

After certain number of successful read requests the php just errors out and throws same error over and over. After awhile it can recover. This seems to be on per-app server basis and does not affect all app servers at the same time.

If I pkill mongo and start a new mongos connection, this is usually fixed.
any idea on which direction to dig in or maybe pointers are appreciated, thanks.
this is the error we get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: internal-mongo-r1-d2-dev.myserver.com:27017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { setShardVersion: "", init: true, configdb: "internal-mongo-c1-dev.myserver.com:27019,internal-mongo-c2-dev.myserver.com:27019,internal-mongo-c3-dev.myserver.com:27019", serverID: ObjectId('52f57ce26ca6543144b077e5'), authoritative: true }' in /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/db/mongo/mongo.inc:185
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/db/mongo/mongo.inc(185): MongoCursor->rewind()
#1 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/db/data.inc(62): MongoCG::get(Array)
#2 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/data/session/savedsession.inc(30): Data::select('mongo', 'coll_saved_sess...', '_id', 'updated_ss', Array, Array)
#3 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/data/session/savedsession.inc(20): SavedSession::select(Array)
#4 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/access/phpsession.inc(32): SavedSession::get_one('fl0uq0nqjbbo4iq...')
#5 [internal function]: PhpSession::read('fl0uq0nqjbbo4iq...')
#6 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/access/phpsession.inc(16): session_start()
#7 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/allinc.inc(15): PhpSession::start()
#8 /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/p.php(4): include_once('/mnt/home/webap...')
#9 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/home/webapps/cgs-sys/releases/20140207163554/includes/db/mongo/mongo.inc on line 185
```

Comment: When this happens, what does your system load look like?  It appears that you are doing a split or migrate that is trying to commit, and it's blocking for a long time.  If this happens again, take a look at CPU and disk I/O usage, run db.currentOp(), and see if you can find a pileup or stall somewhere (and then update with that data here).

Comment: well, this happens under load, CPU usually runs high during this time, however the place in code where this happens is around where i am trying to read from the database, i have been trying to fix this issue for many hours now and i will be posting an update soon, thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to do a quick follow up.

after digging in we found out that we had a low setting of "open files" on the mongod servers which was fixed, and these errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few references around to similar errors and the general suggestion is the first thing to look at at TCP keepalive.

Apart from the other considerations you may also want to look at keepalive settings in your driver connection.

Some links as a place to start:

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mongodb+transport+error

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/eod_QH9-VIY

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3446

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mongodb+transport+error